# VScode Pylance python file path autocompletion

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance, jedi

Recently I've installed pylance server (earlier I used Jedi), but it turned out that I have my file path autocompletion turned off. In Jedi it is out-of-box. How can I enable this option?

Jedi: [image]

Pylance:
[image]

I tried setting up `"python.analysis.include": ["${workspaceFolder}"]`, but it doesn't do a thing `"python.analysis.indexing": true`  also useless

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature only provided by Jedi. Pylance currently has no such feature.